# How can I change touch id alert icon of default touch id alert?

Tags: ios, touch-id

I want to change touch id **alert icon** of default touch id alert. Please suggest me if anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple, You can't change it, not with official libs or components, don't waste your time on this.